# Substitute known function's derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, symbolic

Suppose I know that the time derivative of $x(t)$ is $\dot{x}(t)=-x(t)$. I consider the function $V(x)=x^2$ and I want to compute the time derivative of $V$ along the trajectories of $x$, namely $\dot{V}(t) = 2x(t)\dot{x}(t) = -2x^2(t)$. I can do it like

```
v[x_] := x^2;
D[v[x[t]], t] /. D[x[t], t] -> -x[t]
```

But then I have to explicitly mention the substitution `D[x[t], t] -> -x[t]` everywhere. Is it possible to define it once, e.g., as a function definition? What is the good practice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially you have

```
v[x_] := x^2;
D[v[x[t]], t]
(* 2 x[t] Derivative[1][x][t] *)
```

to which you can apply the substitution.

If you want this substitution to happen automatically, you can define an "UpValue".  This means that the definition is associated with `x`, rather than `Derivative`.  Note the use of a pure function on the RHS.

```
Derivative[1][x] ^:= (-x[#] &)
```

You then get

```
D[v[x[t]], t]
(* -2 x[t]^2 *)
```

as desired

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie in Mathematica. What is ```^:=```? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Arastas it invokes the function `UpSetDelayed`.  I suggest looking at the documentation for this and the tutorial "Associating Definitions with Different Symbols"

Comment: @Arastas - when you don't recognize something like `^:=`, highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help. Or, hover over it and click on the info icon in the tooltip.

Comment: I have found Defining Derivative section in documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Calculus.html#1054

Is it different from your solution, or it is the same but written in a different way?

Comment: In Mathematica there's often more than one way to do things. I'm not sure whether the different syntax creates the same definition. You can examine the definitions created to see.